# What is an effective way to unit test code where private variables are necessary to simulate behaviour?

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm trying to write tests for a code project I have to do for school.
I have to build a little music platform.

I have a 'playlist' class where I have a list of 'songs'.
I have a integer counter which is basically an index of which song is playing.
This is necessary because of the 4 different modes of playing the playlist:
On shuffle, repeating the list, stopping at the end, and repeating the same track.

I am specifically trying to test if the logic that handles these "modes" is working like it should:

```
public class PlayList : IPlaylistCallback
{
    public int PlaylistID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    private List<int> _shuffleTrackIndexes = new List<int>();
    private int _currentTrackPosition = 0;
    private int _currentShufflePosition = 0;

    public PlayList()
    {
        
    }
    
    private void HandleShuffleList(bool dirNext)
    {
        _currentShufflePosition = dirNext ? ++_currentShufflePosition : --_currentShufflePosition;

        if (_currentShufflePosition == _shuffleTrackIndexes.Count || _currentShufflePosition == -1 || _shuffleTrackIndexes.Count == 0)
        {
            _shuffleTrackIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, (Songs.Count - 1)).OrderBy(item => new Random().Next()).ToList();
            _currentShufflePosition = 0;
        }
        
        _currentTrackPosition = _shuffleTrackIndexes.ElementAt(_currentShufflePosition);
    }

    public void OnTrackEnd()
    {
        switch (PlayMode._Mode)
        {
            case PlayMode.PlayModes.RepeatTrack:
                Songs.ElementAt(_currentTrackPosition).Play(false);
                break;
            case PlayMode.PlayModes.RepeatList:
                _currentTrackPosition = _currentTrackPosition == (Songs.Count - 1) ? 0 : ++_currentTrackPosition;
                Songs.ElementAt(_currentTrackPosition).Play( false);
                break;
            case PlayMode.PlayModes.Endlist:
                if (_currentTrackPosition != Songs.Count - 1)
                {
                    Songs.ElementAt(++_currentTrackPosition).Play(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    _currentTrackPosition = 0;
                }
                break;
            case PlayMode.PlayModes.Shuffle:
                HandleShuffleList(true);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have written a test method that tests if the playlist stops playing if it is at the end of the list.

```
[Test]
public void NextTrackShouldEndList()
{
      PlayMode._Mode = PlayMode.PlayModes.Endlist;
      _playList._currentTrackPosition = _playList.Songs.Count - 1;
      _playList.OnTrackEnd();
      Assert.That(_playList.Songs.Count(p => p.Playing), Is.EqualTo(0));
}
```

As you see I need 2 private variables in the testing method to simulate the behavior. But according to this website I shouldn't use private variables. What is a good alternative? Or have I understood it wrong and could I use private variables to simulate behavior? If so, should I just make them public temporary for the sake of the test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be unit testing implementation details, but more urgently, your class isn't exposing enough surface area (public members) to make unit testing possible. For example, the current track position should be exposed by a read-only property and changing the current track needs to be done by a method (although it *could* be done using a read-write property, but you might need parameters).

Comment: Furthermore, you've exposed *too much* surface area in other parts.  The `Songs` property gives unfettered access to the list of songs. Modifying that list happens without updating the internal state of `PlayList`, so doing anything on that collection (e.g. calling `Clear` - *gasp!*) could cause `PlayList` to throw an exception when its state doesn't match the list's state.

Comment: Start over. Define the public members, have them throw `NotImplementedException`, and then write your unit tests. See them all fail miserably, as they should at this stage.  Then implement and adjust each member until everything passes.